# VB script to format excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file which is generated by another program. for this reason it is a Microsoft Excel Workbook and not a Macro-enabled workbook.

I am wanting to write a VB script which does basic formatting to the excel file without having to call an embedded macro.

Is this possible? I have been searching for a while but only found a VB script which calls the embedded macro (as below):

VB Script:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("test.xls")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test value"

objExcel.Application.Run "Macro.TestMacro()"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close


objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Calling macro:

```
Sub TestMacro()
'example
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code.  the tags include usage guidance

Answer (score 0):

A common trick is to use **two** workbooks:

- Master.xlsm
- test.xls

The Master will contain the macros(s) to:

1. create or open test.xls
2. modify and format test.xls
3. save and close test,xls